# Hola, como puedo llamar un archivo js en mi archivo ts?

Tags: angular

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ahorcado',
  templateUrl: './ahorcado.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ahorcado.component.css']
})
export class AhorcadoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera, tienes tu archivo custom.js.

Dentro tienes la siguiente función.

```
function funcionCustom() {
      console.log('Se ejecuto la funcion')
}
```

En tu index.html de angular, llamas el js

```
<script src="tu_ruta/custom.js"></script>
```

Ahora dentro de tu componente dentro de ngOnInit puedes llamar la funcion de la siguiente manera:

```
ngOnInit() {
funcionCustom();}
```

En el navegador puedes ver la console y debera mistrar el mensaje de la funcion.

Comment: al hacer este procedimiento me marca un espantoso error...

Comment: Cual es el error que te marca?

Comment: al momento que llamo la funcion principal de mi java script en el ts por ejemplo: en mi ngOnInit(){ ejcutar();  } me dice: [ts] cannot fin name 'ejecutar, y ya referencie mi archivo js en el index.html de Angular. y verifique  que la ruta del archivo js este correcta

Comment: declare function ejcutar(); agrega esa lina debajo de tus referencias del componente.